# How to trigger data available on a socket to the client without writing any data to it?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, boost-asio, hiredis

I have a peculiar situation. Due to company policies and other factors, I had to write my own library to access a REDIS server. I coded it in C++ and used the C `hiredis` library, using their `async` API. On my end, I used `ASIO`.

In development, things work smoothly, no problems. But in integration/production, I am getting an error of `Resource Temporarily Unavailable`.

Tracking things down to `hiredis`, I see in their `ssl.c` code that they handle `EAGAIN` as a fatal error and cancel all pending requests. I wrote retry logic in my library to deal with this case, but I am unable to reproduce the problem locally, thus I can't determine if my code works.

Hence the question - I would like to modify `redis` source to forcefully cause the error to happen by signaling data availability to the client on the very first request, without actually writing any data to the socket.

The main problem - I don't know how to make that happen.

Comment: [This tutorial](http://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/tcpip_4.25_en/prog_guide/sock_advanced_tut.html) goes into many related topics, several of which could possibly contribute to some additional insight on how you might do this.

Comment: ... eg, under `servers` I read this:  _"A server process normally listens at a well-known port for service requests. That is, the server process remains dormant until a connection is requested by a client's connection to the server's address. At such a time, the server process ``wakes up'' and services the client, performing whatever appropriate actions the client requests of it."_

Comment: I don't think this is possible? You can't signal data availability without having data available. If you could, that would be an operating system bug.

Comment: A socket is readable when it has actual data waiting to be read - for a listening socket, that means a pending client connection, for other sockets that means actual byte data (including a `FIN` closure). There is no way to force/simulate a socket's readability otherwise. You would have to use a separate pipe or sync object to wait on, which you can then write to or signal when needed. Sounds like the hiredis library is not designed to handle non-blocking sockets, where `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` is common, only blocking sockets, where `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` should never happen.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.